# Multiple talk short url?

Tags: c, curl

I have a problem with creating multiple talk short URLs. I would create one by using a site. It didn't work although I imported the code on Postman. I couldn't find the solution anywhere. Which steps should I follow?

````
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://umuly.com/api/url/TalkUrlMultipleAdd");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
  struct curl_slist headers = NULL;
  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
  curl_mime *mime;
  curl_mimepart *part;
  mime = curl_mime_init(curl);
  part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
  curl_mime_name(part, "Urls[0].Title");
  curl_mime_data(part, "", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
  part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
  curl_mime_name(part, "Urls[0].Description");
  curl_mime_data(part, "", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
  part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
  curl_mime_name(part, "Urls[0].Content");
  curl_mime_data(part, "", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
  part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
  curl_mime_name(part, "Urls[0].Tags");
  curl_mime_data(part, "", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
  part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
  curl_mime_name(part, "DomainID");
  curl_mime_data(part, "", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, mime);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_mime_free(mime);
}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);```
````

Comment: What language is this? What does "doesn't work" mean - do you get an error, or just not the expected result? Is that the actual code you're running, or is there some data you've removed in the curl_mime_data lines?

Comment: It's written as C language. I got an error called 401 Unauthorized. What can cause that problem?